# c++11 enums - use of enum without previous declaration error

Tags: c++, enums

```
enum category : char {
  store = 's',
  query = 'q'
};
```

I am getting an error

error: use of enum ‘category’ without previous declaration
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘:’ token

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you enable C++11? Have you looked at your compiler's documentation for whether it supports this feature?

Comment: How do I enable C++11?

Comment: It's just `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @chris It is in GCC and Clang, but not universally.

Comment: @mariner If you're using C++11, prefer to use "enum class", unless you specifically require an old style enum.

Comment: @polkadotcadaver, Well, there's MSVC left, which has them enabled by default, and then there's ICC with `/Qstd=c++11`. It's usually pretty safe to assume one of these is being used. It's in the compiler's documentation in any case.